# How to clean project before each build?

Tags: xcode

Is there a way (possibly using schemes) in Xcode to specify that a clean is automatically done before doing a new build.?

I have a project that sometimes fails to build unless I do a clean first, currently I am doing it by hand.

Comment: Don't ask me *how*, but I'm pretty sure you can do that with a build script.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Press ⌥⌘R, expand the selected scheme, select Pre-actions, click +, select New Run Script Action, set Provide Build Settings from to your target. In the box below type `rm -rf ${BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR}`. Note: it is BUILT not BUILD as seen in the Xcode dialog. You can type `echo ${BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR} > ~/Desktop/log.txt` to see what's going to be deleted.

Comment: That was simpler then I thought. I would have used the `xcodebuild` command line tool, but that's equally as good. +1

Answer (score 3):

The selected answer did not work for me, it caused my build to fail (Xcode 4.6.3) when trying to run on the simulator.
Based on Jano's answer and on this [link](http://www.crickettechnology.com/blog/?p=671) in the Pre-action script instead of writing

```
rm -rf ${BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR}
```

I wrote

```
touch ${BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR}
```

This should have the same effect and it doesn't cause my build to fail

Comment: how does removing BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR have the same effect as touching BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR?  They do completely different things.  The latter command doesn't remove or clean anything at all.

Comment: What I meant is that they both (rm and touch) helped with the failing builds issue but when using rm it caused my build to fail because Xcode complained it can't find the folder, I added as an answer in case someone else with the same issue arrives to this page like I did