# How could I know if a .xcodeproj/.xcworkspace is opened by Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, macos

When the .xcodeproj/.xcworkspace is opened by Xcode, I cannot clean up DerivedData from CLI

Answer (score 0):

Instead of trying to do this via the CLI, or Command Line Interface, why not add in a Build Phase into your project so that way the Derived Data folder gets erased each time you do a build?

To do that, you open up your target's setting and go to build phases.  Then add a new "Run Script" phase like this:

[image: Add RunScript phase]

Reorder the RunScript phase to position 2 so that it will run before doing any building, and then enter in a "`rm -rf {BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR`" bit, [like what is found in this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7349073/xcode-4-clean-before-build).
[image: And]

And RunScript reordering won't work for WatchOS apps, b.t.w. I just discovered that tonight.