# XCode - how to clean and compile in one operation?

Tags: xcode, swift

The code below fails at runtime because the photo member was removed from the Meal class.  However the standard XCode build compiles successfully as there is no clean done by default.

Why is the default build option not to clean first and how can you get XCode to clean and build in one op?  I'm coming from the Java/Maven world where the standard build does both (`mvn clean install`).

```
class Myclass {
    var meals = [Meal]()

    override func blah(...) {
        let meal = meals[x]
        cell.photoImageView.image = meal.photo
        ...
   }
```

Comment: You should post all necessary code to replicate the issue, this example is too vague to completely demonstrate it.

Comment: Ok it looks like I needed to do a clean first then the build failed.   Sorry I'm a Swift newbie.

Comment: We all start somewhere, glad you figured it out!

Comment: Updated question in the form of how to clean and build in one step as opposed to why is build not failing

Comment: It's quite obvious that you are mismatching a few things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would guess that they don't clean automatically before building because that would make some projects very unwieldy. If a lot needs to be built then you can save considerable development time in relying on previous build products and just building what needs to be built.

If you want to perform a clean and build in one step you can follow this answer:

[Clean before build](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7349252/887210)